# Launch Google Spreadsheet function remotely?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-maps-api-2

Hopefully this is the last step in automating a little piece of my workflow.

1. Windows scheduler/vbs performs a collection of exports from our SFDC app - done
2. Windows scheduler/vbs imports the exported data into database tables - done
3. Windows scheduler/vbs runs SQL queries to produce the necessary data collections to produce Google Maps app data, then drops the result into my Google Drive as a .csv file - done
4. Added a function to a Published Google Spreadsheet to import the csv data into the spreadsheet.  But, requires a manual click on spreadsheet to accomplish - done
5. Google Maps app points to the google spreadsheet data via JSON call - done

Question - Any way remotely run the function in the Google Spreadsheet, or at least automate the manual "click" on mentioned in step (4).

Hope you can assist.

Thanks!

PS>  I did look at JDBC options for the data, but that's more than I'd like to tackle for this last piece - Java is outside my narrow skillset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, this is possible.

At the moment I'm guessing you have a button on the top of your spreadsheet that says something like "Import from CSV" and this then runs a function from your Google Scripts. You can go to the script manager and set a trigger to run this script at specific times in the day.

**Triggers are in**

`Tools > Script Manager > *EDIT SCRIPT* > Resources > Triggers`

Comment: Yes!  That is exactly what I was looking for.

My other scripts refresh the data periodically, So I can trigger that function a few minutes behind the others.

Would be nice to have programmatic remote control of the function to  handle some of the on-demand options in my workflow.

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes it would be nice to be able to trigger it remotely from another script, and this might be possible using GSS API but I haven't had a look. One thing I will mentioned is that the triggers have a quota on 1) How long the script runs for and 2) how much data can be transferred in a 24h period.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do it with triggers. Simply publish a script in the ss as contentservice. Pass the csv as a parameter. Script then imports csv into ss.